# Generic rotation to remove Quadratic Cross-product

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, conic-sections, rotations

Show that if $b\neq 0$, then the cross-product term can be eliminated from the quadratic $ax^2 + 2bxy + cy^2$ by rotating the coordinate axes through an angle $\theta$ that satisfies the equation $$
      \cot{2\theta}=\frac{a-c}{2b}.
    $$

I know that $ax^2 + 2bxy + cy^2$ can be rewritten as $$
\begin{bmatrix}x&y\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix},
$$ and I am familiar with how to rotate it using unitary matrices. However, it is very tedious to find the eigenvectorss of $$
\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&c\end{bmatrix}.
$$ Is there a method for solving this problem that does not require finding the eigenvectors?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_eigenvalue_algorithm.
I think this link will be helpful i.e reducing any nxn symmetric to a diagonal matrix by using plane rotations without finding the eigenvectors it got reduced into Diagonal form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working directly with the rotation substitution $x=cx'-sy',\ y=sx'+cy',$ where $c=\cos \theta,\ s=\sin \theta,$ we need only compute the resulting coefficient of $x'y'$ and set it to zero. From the form $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2$ this coefficient is
$$a(-2sc)+2b(c^2-s^2)+c(2sc),$$ and then (assuming $b \neq 0$) we have
$$\frac{a-c}{2b}=\frac{c^2-s^2}{2sc}=\frac{\cos 2\theta}{\sin 2\theta}=\cot(2 \theta),$$
the desired formula.

Note: maybe it's a bad choice to use $s,c$ for the sine and cosine of the rotation angle, since $c$ also appears in the form $ax^2+2bxy+cy^2.$ However I think it's clear which is which in the above so I'll leave it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

if you are diagonalizing the matrix $A,$ then there is no way you can avoid the eigenvectors and eigenvalues. the diagonal entries are the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u$ and $v$ be the rotated coordinates. That is,
$$
\begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}.
$$
You want to be able to substitute a quadratic with no $uv$ term for the quadratic 
$ax^2 + bxy + cy^2.$  That is, you want there to be fixed coefficients $p$ and $q$ such that
$$ pu^2 + qv^2 = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 \tag{1}$$
for every pair $(x,y).$

It's slightly tedious, but not difficult, to write $u$ and $v$ each in terms of
$x,$ $y,$ and $\theta,$ and to plug these substitutions into $pu^2 + qv^2.$
If you collect the terms in $x^2,$ in $xy,$ and in $y^2,$
knowing that the result must equal $ax^2 + bxy + cy^2,$ you can deduce
the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$ in terms of these other parameters.

Now see if you can take $a - c$ in those terms and make it look like
$(\mathit{something})\times \cos 2\theta.$
If you can then make $2b$ look like
$(\mathit{the\ same\ thing})\times \sin 2\theta,$
you will have proved your desired result.

You can avoid carrying around all those factors of $x^2,$ $xy,$ and $y^2$
if you rewrite Equation $(1)$ using the matrices 
$\begin{pmatrix} p&0 \\ q&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} a&b \\ x&d \end{pmatrix}$
and the vectors $\begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \end{pmatrix}$ and
$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix},$ and peform the obvious substitution
for $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ immediately; you can then derive a
matrix equation that doesn't involve $x$ or $y$ at all.
That notation may be a bit more agreeable with your initial thoughts on the problem.