# About Jacobi Method for computing eigenvalues of matrices ( Trefethen and Bau Numerical Linear Algebra Lecture 30 Question 30.1

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra, rotations, diagonalization

Here, the problem is to derive the following formula for Jacobi Method for computing the eigenvalues of a matrix A, by diagonalizing  sub-matrix of A in which the real $2$$\times$$2$ symmetric matrix can be diagonalized in the form

$J^T$$\begin{pmatrix}a&d\\d&b\end{pmatrix}$ $J$   =  $\begin{pmatrix}\ne0&0\\0&\neq0\end{pmatrix}$,

where $J$ is orthognal.

What would be the precise geometric interpretation of the transformation; $tan$$2\theta$= $\frac{2d}{b-a}$ based on the choice of $\theta$ ?

Comment: You might wish to go back and review your conic sections. The rotation used here is precisely the rotation needed to remove the cross-term $xy$ in the implicit Cartesian equation of a conic section. In terms of the corresponding quadratic form, removing the $xy$ term is precisely a diagonalization. See e.g. [this older thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065737).